# Boost C++ Unit Testing Code Coverage TeamCity

Tags: c++, boost, teamcity, code-coverage

Please excuse what may appear to be a novice question. I have searched on the net for awhile without results.

Is it possible to get code coverage on TeamCity using the Boost C++ Unit testing framework and how would one be able to factor this in Teamcity.

Comment: You're in luck!  This question has been [previously asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491489/running-boost-unit-test-console-applications-as-part-of-teamcity-build).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but looking for code coverage instead of unit testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google suggests that Boost does not provide code coverage.  Instead, folks typically generate coverage stats with [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) ([see also](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php)).  An important feature of lcov is that you can [generate an HTML-formatted report](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/genhtml.1.html) of its code coverage statistics.

Happily for us, TeamCity is configured by default to create a 'Reports' tab with a 'Code Coverage' section in your build history. (You can verify this by browsing to `Administration` -> `Report Tabs`.)  To take advantage of this, you must provide TeamCity with a build artifact containing the coverage HTML.

1. In TeamCity, browse to the configuration/template in which you're doing the testing
2. Browse to the 'General Settings' section of the build configuration
3. In the *Artifacts* text box, enter the following:

   `$PATH_TO_LCOV_OUTPUT_DIR=>coverage.zip`

TeamCity will look for an `index.html` file in the `coverage.zip` artifact and display that as the report.